# Are return types important for the ide to determine which of the overloaded methods will be called?

Tags: java, spring-boot, overloading, wrapper, primitive-types

In my controller class I have such a method

```
RequestMapping(value = "/getSomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_A') and hasRole('ROLE_B') " +
            "and @securityService.control1(#intParam)") // causing an error
    @Override
    public List<smth> getSomething(@ReuestParam("param") int intParam) {
        ...
        return.. 
    }
```

and security service like this

```
boolean control1(Integer param); // can not find this
boolean control1();
```

for some reason I need overloading methods in security service and when I use **boolean** as return type, ide can not find the method with Integer parameter in @PreAuthorize annotation. But if I change boolean to **Boolean** there is no problem. So I wonder why this happens?

Comment: You need to show the error in your question.

Comment: @tgdavies simply says "Different number of formal and actual parameters"